# Почему питон выводит список слитно

Tags: python, python-3.x

пишу вот такой код по книге

```
ShopList = ['яблоки', 'морковь', 'манго', 'бананы']

print('Я должен сделать', len(ShopList), 'покупки.')

print("Покупки:", end='')
for item in ShopList:
    print(item, end='')

print('\nТакже нужно купить риса.')
ShopList.append('рис')
print('Теперь мой список таков:', ShopList)
```

выдает мне такой результат

```
Я должен сделать 4 покупки.
Покупки:яблокиморковьмангобананы
Также нужно купить риса.
Теперь мой список таков: ['яблоки', 'морковь', 'манго', 'бананы', 'рис']
```

Я не могу понять почему мне питон выдает строчку покупки слитно при том что в книге получается список раздельный. как это можно исправить кроме того чтобы просто добавить пробелов в ручную?

Comment: https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-print

Comment: ну если верить этому руководству то я правильно все написал. но так и не понял почему мне выводит слитно покупки

Comment: замените `end=''` на `end=' '`

Comment: до меня щас дошло, `print(item, end='')` надо было пробел поставить) спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 6):

В вашей книге, скорее всего, вместо `print(item, end='')` написано `print(item, end=' ')`, т.е. аргумент `end` равен не пустой строке, а пробелу.

Answer (score -1):

В скобках `' '` у `end` поставь внутри пробел и запятую и будет выводить нормально. Как надо: `end = '  , '`.

Функция `for` выдает по 1 значению каждый раз на новой строке, `end`, печатает все значения в одну строку сплошняком, а в скобках `end`, как раз и указывается каким способом разделять выводные данные.